# C++ Prevent CMD Commands being used

Tags: c++, error-handling, cmd, command

Apologies for the (previous?) poorly worded question

I am trying to prevent CMD commands being used. Specifically F6 is the only button I can't work around. Entering F6 closes the program or loops the userName() function.

Due to F6 or Ctr+Z being a direct command to enter a loop. 
It has caused my program to act un-predictably. 
On one machine it loops infinitely, on my own it just shuts downt the window

Part of my assessment that has been driving me nuts since i started it.  Many of my peers are also having issues with it, but it was a direct request that it's an immediate 'fail' if he can crash our program. Thats why i'm being persistent on only allowing the characters defined below:

```
 size_t found = user.find_first_not_of("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890");
```

As requested also enough of the program to replicate the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <cstddef>   
string name = { "" };
int menu();
int errorChecking(string user);
int userName();

    int main() 
{
    cout  << "-------------------- Welcome! --------------------"  << endl << endl;

    userName();

}

int errorChecking(string user)
{
    size_t found = user.find_first_not_of("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890");
    if (found != string::npos)
    {
        cout << name[found] << " is not an acceptable character." << '\n';
        cout << "Enter a valid name ";
        cout << endl << endl;
        userName();
    }

    return(0);

}

int userName()
{

    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    std::getline(cin, name);
    //if (name == "→") { cin.clear(); userName(); }
    errorChecking(name);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `cin >>` does not "infinitely loop" - there is no looping statement. What does the rest of your code - the part that contains the loop - look like?

Comment: Do you remember to [clear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the stream status?

Comment: With cin, cout and string you are already using the standard libraries. It's really hard to write anything without the standard libraries unless you rewrite a chunk of the standard libraries first.

Comment: `cin` is already part of the standard library

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> keystroke, at a Windows terminal prompt, indicates "end of file". When `cin` encounters an end of file, the stream enters an error state and no further calls to `std::getline(cin, name)` will actually wait for the user to type any input.

What you need to do is handle the stream error state appropriately. One way to do this might be:

```
cout << "Enter your name: ";
std::getline(cin, name);
if (!cin) {
    cerr << "Unexpected end of file encountered on cin\n";
    exit(1);
}
errorChecking(name);
```

You may of course take whatever other action you like instead of calling `exit(1)`.

Comment: Thanks a tonne, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realise it was possible to say !cin or if("Actually we didn't get any input")

Comment: And just had to add a cin.clear(); before recalling the userName(); function.